# Manually finding a position in a string

Tags: ios, string

I have a large attributed string which is my body text and I need to insert 10 titles into it at various locations.

I know where they need to go, and they wont move from that position so I can use `insertAttributedString:atIndex:` in a loop to add them all.

My issue is finding the index value in the main string where I want it inserting. Anybody know of an easier way than manually counting through thousands of characters till I get to the title's position??

Comment: "manually counting"? What do you mean? Give the code you are contemplating, and someone will tell you if it can be improved.

Comment: Sorry if the question was a little vague... The body text is actually being loaded in from a .txt file so when I say manually counting, i mean going to the start of the .txt file and counting everytime I press the right arrow on my keyboard until I get to the point in the text file where I want the title to go! I hoping there is a menu in xcode or an external program which will tell me the index of the point where my cursor is rather than the counting method (apologies if the question sounded like it should be done in code - this wouldnt be possible!)

Comment: Could you insert your cursor and type `***insertHere1***` etc, then use code to find these placeholders and replace them? That seems like a plausible approach given what you are describing... combine that with Antonio's answer, and you have a working solution.

Comment: Yes, rather than counting and embedding the counts in your code, use tokens like `&1`, `&2`... or `**location1**`, `**location2**` to identify the spots and then you can use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` or some such for your substitution.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but using an external program to find the index (TextWrangler as suggested below) will work just fine - i presumed xcode might have that feature but using another program would be alot easier than using the placeholders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason you're trying to do this in XCode as it doesn't sound like you're trying to accomplish this programmatically? Since, to your point, XCode doesn't support character count I would download something like TextWrangler (free in Mac App Store) so you can get an easy character line count in your file.

Comment: No, it doesnt need to be done in xcode, its just I came across the problem while using it and thought there might be a way to do it in XCode. Ive downloaded TextWrangler and that is exactly what I was after. Thankyou very much!

Comment: Just one more quick thing, TextWrangler doesnt tell me the exact character position, just the line number and what position the character is on that line. Do you know if it can be set up to tell me the absolute character position, or recommend any other program which will?

Comment: The best workaround I can think of is to remove line breaks (they will show up as spaces instead) [via Text->Remove Line Breaks] followed by turning on SoftWrap via [View->Text Display->Soft Wrap Text] so that you now have your entire file on a single line but is wrapped & viewable. I typically use UltraEdit for work like that (free for 30 days - paid license worth it) by changing my text into Hex Mode which will give me absolute position.

Answer (score 1):

To get the index of a NSString, use this:

```
NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"MyString"];
```

If there are several occurrences, you can loop trough them with this:

```
NSUInteger count = 0, length = [str length];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, length); 
while(range.location != NSNotFound)
{
  range = [str rangeOfString: @"cake" options:0 range:range];
  if(range.location != NSNotFound)
  {
    range = NSMakeRange(range.location + range.length, length - (range.location + range.length));
    count++; 
  }
}
```